# Grunt Browserify max call stack size exceeded

Tags: gruntjs, reactjs, browserify

I am using grunt-browserify to compile my react/flux application. I've also enabled Watchify under browserify options so speed up the compile process. It compiles fine when first run, but once I change a file and it compiles again, a `Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded` error appears in the browser's console and breaks the application.

It seems that Watchify is adding react/flux/other dependencies again on a recompile which causes the error. Just a theory.

Any ideas?

#### Grunt Task

```
browserify: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'public/dist/bundle.js': ['public/js/**/*.jsx', 'public/js/**/*.js']
    },
    options: {
      debug: true,
      bare: true,
      alias: [
        './node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js:react',
        './node_modules/flux/index.js:flux',
        './public/lib/react-router/react-router.js:react-router',
        './node_modules/lodash/index.js:lodash'
      ],
      transform: [react.browserify],
      watch: true,
      keepAlive: true
    }
  }
}
```

#### Register

```
grunt.registerTask('compile', ['browserify']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ignore 'public/dist/bundle.js' for watching ?